# Variance of a row-vector?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have calculated the following vector 
$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{-1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \xi), \frac{n}{2\sigma^2} - \frac{1}{2\sigma^4} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \xi)^2 \end{bmatrix}$$
Each $X_i$ is iid normal with mean $\xi$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

I now want the variance of this vector. I have the solution at hand, but don't quite understand the calculations. Do we create a matrix where we take variance on the diagonals, and covariances off the diagonals? If so, how do I calculate covariances of this tricky-looking thing?

Comment: Is the second component supposed to be $\dfrac{n}{2\sigma^2}$ or $\dfrac{n}{2}\sigma^2$?

Answer (score 0):

In principle a random vector $\overrightarrow{Y}=\left(Y_{1},\dots,Y_{n}\right)^{T}:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$
has no variance but has a covariance matrix $\Sigma=\left(\Sigma_{i.j}\right)$
with entries: $$\Sigma_{i.j}=\text{Cov}\left(Y_{i},Y_{j}\right)$$

If $U,V$ are random variables and $a,b,c,d$ are constants then: $$\text{Cov}(aU+c,bV+d)=ab\text{Cov}(U,V)$$
Also we have: $$\text{Cov}(U,U)=\text{Var}(U)$$

In your case it is quite handsome to substitute: $$U_i:=\frac{X_i-\xi}{\sigma}$$ which has standard normal distribution, so has mean $0$ and variance $1$.

These facts can simplify your calculations considerably.